# How display images on each iteration (ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

please help to resolve the following issues: 
There is a page which loads the image. 
50 pictures.
How to make,  that images would be  displayed gradually (example google photo)?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: document.location.href,
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {'ajax-query': 'true'}
            success: function(data){
                $('#divgallery').append(data);
            }
        });
    })
```

Here comes the  server code

```
    if($i=0; $i<50;$i++){   echo '<img src="/img/' . $img . '">';   }
```

They are displayed all at once, after the server-side code is done.
How display images on each iteration?
Any tips, link or code example would be useful.

Comment: you want them to be appended one by one with some delay, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, on the server site return the image links in such way that they can be retrieved individually. I recommend `JSON` fromat.

```
$res = array();
if($i=0; $i<50;$i++){  $res[] = '<img src="/img/' . $img . '">';   }
echo json_encode($res);
```

Secondly, after you get the data you have to add the images one by one, but with a delay between the additions.

```
       success: function(data){
            delayAppend($("#divgallery"), data, 0);
        }
```

And the `delayAppend` function would be something like:

```
function delayAppend($div, data, index){
   if(index >= data.length)
      return;

   $div.append(data[index]);
   setTimeout(function(){ delayAppend($div, data, index+1); }, 500);
}
```

Here is a demo of the `delayAppend` function: http://jsfiddle.net/s7Q8W/

Note: Code not fully tested.

Comment: Is it possible to not return all data in its entirety, but part?
Iteration executed and picture appeared on the client

Comment: You can. Make your server-side function accept a parameter which states what images should it return (eg. from 20 to 30) and only return them.